# SQL - very complicated query

Tags: mysql, sql

im having hard time with a big complicated query I wrote:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name,e.age, e.area, e.date,e.private, e.place, p.*, COUNT(user) AS attending
 FROM events AS e
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT user, event
 FROM attendance
 ) AS a
 ON a.event = e.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT name AS place_name, id as idd, nz AS place_loc, coor
 FROM places
 ) AS p
 ON p.idd = e.place
 where (e.age LIKE "%{17-18}" OR e.age LIKE "%{18-19}" OR e.area LIKE "%{1}" OR e.area LIKE "%{2}" OR e.area LIKE "%{4}" OR e.area LIKE "%{6}" OR e.area LIKE "%{32}" OR e.area LIKE "%{37}" OR e.private LIKE '%id%' )
 GROUP BY e.id, e.name
 ORDER BY attending DESC

 limit 0,7
```

This query give me events, it sorts them by attendance table, and also it gives me the information about the place that the event is on.

anyway, the problem is in WHERE area... every user has different ages and areas. example:
ages: {17-18},{20-22} areas: {0},{1},{2}

every event has the same thing - ages and areas... i am trying to find a match:

if event is set: ages- {15-16},{17-18} and the user is set at least one of them, it will match.

**i dont mind changing the way i store the ages and areas.. i am sure i am not doing it well by using { } , all i want is a way to set user preference where he can save area codes and ages range, and then i want to select from events only the event that matche with the user ages and areas.**

thank you very much! very appriciated

Comment: Woah, the problem is not *just* the where area. You don't need so many subqueries, you can just use the tables in the outer join...

Comment: And, sorry to say, this is NOT a complicated query. A complicated query is at least 5 times longer. A *really* complicated query is 10KB when saved into a text file. :)

Comment: Are places and areas related? Or does "area" mean "area of interest" (like computers, dancing, martial arts, etc)?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: areas means cities... places means structres... clubs pubs etc..

Answer (score 4):

First of all, remove the subqueries. You can write the query using the joins alone:

```
SELECT 
  e.id, e.name,e.age, e.area, e.date,e.private, e.place, 
  p.name AS place_name, p.id as idd, p.nz AS place_loc, p.coor
  COUNT(user) AS attending
FROM 
  events AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   attendance a
ON 
  a.event = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 places p
ON 
  p.idd = e.place
WHERE 
  e.age LIKE "%{17-18}" OR e.age LIKE "%{18-19}" OR e.area LIKE "%{1}" OR e.area LIKE "%{2}" OR e.area LIKE "%{4}" OR e.area LIKE "%{6}" OR e.area LIKE "%{32}" OR e.area LIKE "%{37}" OR e.private LIKE '%id%' )
 GROUP BY e.id, e.name
 ORDER BY attending DESC
 LIMIT 0,7
```

Now, start on the logic. Why are you storing event ages like that? Can each event just have ONE minimum and ONE maximum age, or do you need a range?

For one minimum and maximum age, your where-clause becomes a simple user.age between e.min and e.max.

Same thing for multiple ranges, you'll have a table 'range' that links the event id to the min-age, max-age, and you'll join the event to its ages.

Comment: thanks, min and max age is good for me... what about the areas? lets say i have 30 areas (Cities) ... how can i do that?

Comment: Add an extra table that links the event to the area. Traditionally, three columns are needed: ID, EVENT_ID, AREA_ID. Join this table too, and include the area_id in your where clause. **You should read up on normalization**.